# Facebook 'like' not applying to page likes

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, facebook

Using Heroku I have an Iframe with a `like` button. When the user clicks on `like` it does indeed like the page but other `likes` on the page don't vanish.

This is my listener

```
  FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {    
  var user = '<?php echo idx($basic, 'name'); ?>'
  var uid = '<?php echo idx($basic, 'id'); ?>'
  $.post("utils.php", { user: user , method:'like', uid:uid},
   function(data) {
      $(".codeContainer").html(data.status);
      $(".counterContainer").html(data.voucher);
    },"json");  
  });
```

This asks for a promo code and posts it back. Do I need to do a manual reload? Also how do I bind other FB likes on the page to this function?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the iframe like HTML, use the HTML5 or xfbml version in your code. Then you can subscribe to the edge.create event.

See also: [If facebook is no longer supporting fbml / xfbml and the event handlers provided for them then what is the alternative for iframes?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8791476/if-facebook-is-no-longer-supporting-fbml-xfbml-and-the-event-handlers-provided)